# How to get Linksys WUSB54Gv2 working with Ubuntu 12.04.5 (32-bit)

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, dell, adapter

The older Dell tower (Dell Dimension 4600) that i'm using doesn't have Wi-Fi built in (duh) and Ubuntu will not accept my network adapter. I have another computer to download files to and use to transfer them I just do not have internet connection on the computer in question. Kinda new to Ubuntu so I am completely in the dark right now, any help is greatly appreciated. Using lsusb command brings up "Linksys WUSB54G v2 802.11g Adapter [Intersil ISL3887]"

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lsusb Thanks.

Comment: Added info from using lsusb command to question

Comment: Doesn't it bring up more than that, like the usb.id??

Answer (score 0):

Try To Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 It has got new kernel with more drivers, So That might work. Else Look for instruction for updating the kernel in ubuntu 12.04.5.

Comment: Is there any way I could do that via USB transfer from another computer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your device only needs firmware. Please download this file and drag and drop it to your desktop: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/l/linux-firmware-nonfree/linux-firmware-nonfree_1.11_all.deb

Install in from the terminal with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Unplug and replug the device and tell us if it's working.

Comment: I figured it out, just forgot to update. thanks though